# Does this art style in Hannes Johannes animations have a name?

Tags: style, style-identification

I am really in to this kind of art style:

http://www.hannesjohannes.com/

It heavily features lines and dots to create textures and shading. Is there a specific name for that kind of style? The image below is a really good example of what I am talking about, note the dots around the edges.

[image]

Comment: http://www.hannesjohannes.com/20869/about

Comment: @Ilan that's a good description (I hadn't noticed the 'Beavis & Butthead' similarity before) but not really a name. This style seemed to be everywhere around 2010-2013, I'm sure it must have a name but I never noticed one (except for some people who don't like it dismissing it as 'hipster art'... but that's a broad brush...)

Comment: The edit to the question is good. I would say this picture is a really good example: http://m1.behance.net/profiles16/494899/prosite/projects/11638891/2-1051595-1-218x332-b6f4f8151ece8e9c07b476c6edbd5acf.jpg note the heavy use of dots around the edges.

Comment: @user568458 Style should have some particular features.  Here we see animation-like pics, but the first thing I recalled was Aubrey Beardsley http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubrey_Beardsley

Answer (score 1):

You should look into underground comix (yes, with an x). It's a bit strange that they'd name-check Beavis and Butthead or reference 90s comics, when there's a clear influence from an older print tradition.

R. Crumb is the obviously place to start. Though there's a lot of variety in the genre, the commonality tends to a less polished adaptation of older pen and ink techniques (e.g., stippling, cross-hatching), even when working in other media, and a fascination with grotesque forms while documenting real life.